# Display posts ONLY from the current logged in user and current week/year/month Elementor posts

Tags: wp-query, filters, query

I want to show the posts my users have added in three different sections. That would be "Your Posts from This week" and so on. I am currently using:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/currentuser', function( $query ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
    }
} );
```

to display posts by current logged in users. But any idea what I can add to this query to also display posts from current week/month/year?

PS: Sorry for my week English, it is not my first language :)

Comment: You will have to open a ticket with Elementor to ensure you get an answer that is compatible with their code base.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.